# Back button with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two identical HTML pages (**index.html** and **page1.html**) that contain two buttons:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <li class="ui-body ui-body-b ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-last-child">
        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <button id="submit" type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-corner-all">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <button id="cancel" data-direction="reverse" type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-corner-all">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Where one button changes to the second page, and the second button acts like a back button. (Ideally, you can use the first button to get to the second page, and then use the back button on the second page to get back to the first.)

I control this using JavaScript (this only pertains to the **index.html** buttons, but the **page1.html** JS is identical):

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "page1.html",  {
        transition: 'slide',       
        changeHash: true
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '#cancel', function() {
    parent.history.back();
    //$.mobile.back();
});
```

But nothing I try seems to work. I know that the program reaches the `parent.history.back();` because I've set break points in the console, but other than that I have no idea why it will not return to the first page.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`history` is a property from `window` object and not from an html element. So, this should work:

```
window.history.back();
```

instead of:

```
parent.history.back();
```

At the end you should have something like this:

```
$('button#cancel').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.history.back();
});
```

This is going to also prevent the default behavior of your `submit button`

Comment: Even when I change it to `window.history.back();`, it still does not transition between the pages.

Comment: That is because you button is a submit one and you need to prevent default behavior, I updated the reponse for it

Answer (score 2):

This always worked for me to go back.

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">BACK</a>
```

Comment: If possible, I would love to keep them as `<buttons>` and not `<a>`

Comment: Here: `<button onclick="history.go(-1);">Go back</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Your cancel button is still a submit button, so it's going back *then* submitting the form, sending you forwards again and essentially undoing your back maneuver.

Use

```
return false;
```

after the parent.history.back();

to stop the submission from continuing

Comment: This almost works! But it takes two clicks to get through the function, any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

whith onclick

```
 <a onclick="window.history.back();" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
window.history.back();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet to simulate a back button based on the users last page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.back').click(function(){
    parent.history.back();
    return false;
});
```

});